# How is it possible to enable/disable tabs in Angular 9 where enabling and disabling is based on values from the initial tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How is it possible to enable/disable tabs in Angular 9 where enabling and disabling is based on values from the initial tab?

In an html component having 4 tabs; the initial/first tab have some values depending on which the rest of the 3 tabs become active;

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#1a">Tab 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#1b">Tab 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#1c">Tab 3</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#1d">Tab 4</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'the initial/first tab have some values'? E.g. are you going to have a form for the user on the first tab, and depending on what they submit the other tabs become active?

Comment: Hi Matt ,I have some checkboxes in the first tab where the values are set as true/false respectively, all these values are stored in a local storage in JSON format and based on these values the rest of the tabs should be activated/disabled.How can i achieve this?

Comment: Ah I see - have provided an answer with a working example on Stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a two-way binding on the checkboxes in tab 1 to enable or disable the buttons for your other tabs.

[Here is a basic example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfgdis). Your data structure will probably be more complicated (e.g. setting / getting values from local storage), but the principle will be the same.

In your component:

```
tabs = [true, false, false, false]; 
// True or false indicates whether tab is active. These values are changed by clicking the checkboxes in the first tab

selectedTab= 0;
// Select first tab with checkboxes initially
```

In your template:

```
<!-- Tab Buttons -->

<ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index">
        <button [disabled]="!tab" (click)="selectedTab = i" [ngStyle]="selectedTab === i && {'background':'blue', 'color':'white'}">Show Tab {{i}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab Content -->

<div *ngIf="selectedTab === 0">
    <h3>Tab 0</h3>
    <ul>
        <!-- Controls to enable / disable other tabs -->
        <li>Toggle tab 1 active <input [(ngModel)]="tabs[1]" type="checkbox"></li>
        <li>Toggle tab 2 active <input [(ngModel)]="tabs[2]" type="checkbox"></li>
        <li>Toggle tab 3 active <input [(ngModel)]="tabs[3]" type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedTab === 1">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedTab === 2">
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedTab === 3">
    <h3>Tab 3</h3>
    <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt; This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share information from tab 1 to the parent component. There are a few ways to achieve that:

1. (Recommended) Router params - it will work after page refreshing

In child component set params

```
<button [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{disable: true}">block</button>
<button [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="{disable: false}">unblock</button>
```

In parent component subscribe to params

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.isDisabled = params.disable === 'true';
    })
  }
```

example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhn5ql

2. Service
3. Binding / Event Emitter

Comment: Thanks Michael. I need to activate a disabled tab (say 2nd tab) based on values selected in the first tab.Please check the second comment in the main question block.